# How do I tell an app that the home folder is located somewhere else?

Tags: linux, shell-script, minecraft

Here's the basic script from a batch file. I'm trying to do something similar to this, but on Linux that would tell Minecraft(Java) that the home folder was located somewhere else (like a flash drive). If it's even possible?

```
set APPDATA=%CD%\
start %CD%\minecraft.exe
```

I have a [.zip](http://goo.gl/VwtPJ) file with all the files you would extract to a root of the drive. I've wrapped up the .bat file into the .exe.

Comment: Have you tried googling for "Portable Minecraft"?

Comment: None of them are for Linux. That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The following bash script does what your batch file does. Haven't tested if it works with minecraft, but I'm thinking you probably don't actually want to run a Windows binary on a Linux system, at least not without Wine or something in between.

```
#!/bin/sh
CD="/path/to/whereever"
export HOME="$CD"
"$CD/minecraft.exe"
```

Comment: Is there a special way to have this run .jar files?

Edit: Nevermind. I can get the jar to execute, but it still uses the default home.